# how much time takes to check the compressed file is available or not in that directory while using gzip compression in apache?

Tags: apache-http-server, download, compression, gzip, client-server

I am using static compression.(i.e.)In my application, When xml is generated, then I also creates its gzipped version and place near in it. 

I am having little confusion in it. When clients sends request for data.xml with "Accept-Encoding : gzip" to apache server, then apache in turn checks for gzip file (for example, data.xml.gz ). If it availables, then it sends the zipped file to client, otherwise, it transfers the data.xml. 

My doubt is here only.

**How much time the apache takes to check for zipped file whether it is available or not ?** 

Because I have around 700 to 1000 clients which connects to only one server for that same file to download it. In worst case, if file is not created or not available there, then use of placing condition is waste ( Or ) use of mod_deflate in apache is waste (I felt like that).

Please update me that how much time it takes to complete a single check(whether the file is available or not).

Thanks and Regards,
Ark.

Comment: As it depends on a lot of factors (FS, hard drive etc.) it's probably easier to run it as a test yourself.

Comment: Thanks. But small problem here %{msec_frac} is not working in httpd.conf.

Comment: Which Apache version are you running? This question on Stackoverflow would suggest you need at least Version 2.4: [Sub second request time logging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458906/sub-second-request-time-logging)